# What is substitute for ffmpeg video filter "between" for audio filter

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

i want make a short video preview from long video with audio, but i have problem to select audio stream segments on specific timestamps.
I am using this option for segmenting video

```
-filter_complex "[0:v]select='between(t,216,220.5)+between(t,432,436.5)+between(t,648,652.5)+between(t,864,868.5)+between(t,1080,1084.5)+between(t,1296,1300.5)+between(t,1512,1516.5)+between(t,1728,1732.5)+between(t,1944,1948.5)+between(t,2160,2164.5)'[outv]"
```

and my question is how this option rewrite for audio stream, because when i use just **-filter** without selecting any stream then i get error: *Cannot connect video filter to audio input*

I am using this ffmpeg version:

```
ffmpeg version 3.3.3-static http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/  Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 6.4.0 (Debian 6.4.0-2) 20170724
configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-debug --disable-ffplay --disable-indev=sndio --disable-outdev=sndio --cc=gcc-6 --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --e
nable-gnutls --enable-gray --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopus --enable-librtm
p --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid
libavutil      55. 58.100 / 55. 58.100
libavcodec     57. 89.100 / 57. 89.100
libavformat    57. 71.100 / 57. 71.100
libavdevice    57.  6.100 / 57.  6.100
libavfilter     6. 82.100 /  6. 82.100
libswscale      4.  6.100 /  4.  6.100
libswresample   2.  7.100 /  2.  7.100
libpostproc    54.  5.100 / 54.  5.100
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For audio, you would use

```
"[0:a]aselect='between(t,216,220.5)+...+between(t,2160,2164.5)'[outa]"
```

BYW, the filter name is (a)select. `between` is a eval function used here.